# Is there a way to count how many entries exists with a certain filter for python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, data-science

This might seem very basic but I am new to Pandas, the title might not be accurate but I have good screenshots below
This is sort of a voting app

I have the vote_results dataframe:
[image]

And the legislators dataframe:
[image]

This is the dataframe that I want to accomplish:
[image]

supported bills means a vote for yes
opposed bills means a vote for no
**So I want to know how many times each legislator voted for yes (1) and no(2)
I also need a join on the legislator's dataframe in order to include the legislator name**

Really need some insight on this to understand better what can I do with dataframes in terms of manipulation.

I tried making some joins and group_by's but honestly I am not handling it very well, I can't print my group_by's and also don't know how to create an alias for count positive and negative votes grouped by legislator_id

Comment: need minimal and reproducible code for answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is:

- Join the two dataframes by legislator id
- Group by legislator id
- Aggregate for supported bills and opposed bills count
- Legislator name is the first (or any) one in the group

```py
vote_results = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,"L1","V1",1],[2,"L1","V2",1],[3,"L2","V3",0],[4,"L2","V4",0],[5,"L3","V5",1],[6,"L3","V6",0]], columns=["id","legislator_id","vote_id","vote_type"])

legislators = pd.DataFrame(data=[["L1","ABC"],["L2","PQR"],["L3","XYZ"]], columns=["id","name"])

result_df = legislators.merge(vote_results[["legislator_id","vote_id","vote_type"]], left_on="id", right_on="legislator_id", how="left") \
                       .groupby("id") \
                       .apply(lambda x: pd.Series({
                           "name": str(x["name"].iloc[0]),
                           "num_supported_bills": len([v for v in x.vote_type if v==1]),
                           "num_opposed_bills": len([v for v in x.vote_type if v==0]),
                           })) \
                       .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   id name  num_supported_bills  num_opposed_bills
0  L1  ABC                    2                  0
1  L2  PQR                    0                  2
2  L3  XYZ                    1                  1
```

Comment: Added a fix because 1 for suppo and 2 for opposed:

`result_df = legislators.merge(vote_results[["legislator_id","vote_id","vote_type"]], left_on="id", right_on="legislator_id", how="left") \
                       .groupby("id") \
                       .apply(lambda x: pd.Series({
                           "name": str(x["name"].iloc[0]),
                           "num_supported_bills": len([v for v in x.vote_type if v==1]),
                           "num_opposed_bills": len([v for v in x.vote_type if v==2]),
                           })) \
                       .reset_index()`